# Send Auto Parameter to Stored Procedure in t-sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that can be send a integer parameter

exec stp_GetMaxAbone 100000

i want to make a query that can send all ID column im my fider_data table

Comment: could you please explain it in detail?

Comment: I want to send all ID numbers in fider_data table which with using a loop function to find number of customers that has a same ID. I made stored procedure but I dont know how to send all ID in loop